# java - Should toString() be written as @Override?

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

I know that when overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` for an object in Java, you include the `@Override` tag, but I can't seem to find any documentation stating that you should do the same when overriding `toString()`--shouldn't it be the same since they are all inherited `Object` methods?

Answer (score 3):

You should always include the annotation whenever you're overriding a superclass method.

Comment: Note: it's a *should* not a *must*, but it will be helpful in the long run, so do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should annotate toString() with [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html), though legally there is no such requirement. The annotation @Override prevents the programmer from incorrectly overriding a superclass method; compile-time error occurs in case the override is incorrect.

The ideology is to detect errors as soon as possible after they are made, ideally at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  It's never *necessary* to use the `@Override` annotation, but it's helpful.  From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html:

> While it is not required to use this annotation when overriding a method, it helps to prevent errors. If a method marked with @Override fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error.